# Macro that only runs on 30k rows, but no more

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I have some VB script i found on line, it works well but as long as i ensure the worksheet has no more than 30k rows. I want to run it on a worksheet with 500k rows. When i try, nothing happens. There is barely a change to the cursor and no error message appears. It doesn't hang or crash. Just does nothing. Can anyone suggest an enhancement please?

````
    Dim wrdLRow As Integer
    Dim wrdLp As Integer
    Dim CommentLrow As Integer
    Dim CommentLp As Integer
    Dim fndWord As Integer
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    
    On Error Resume Next 'Suppress Errors... for when we don't find a match
    
    'Define worksheet that has data on it....
    Set Sht = Sheets("ALL")
    
    'Get last row for words based on column A
    wrdLRow = Sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Get last row for comments based on column J
    CommentLrow = Sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Loop through lists and find matches....
    For CommentLp = 2 To CommentLrow
    
        For wrdLp = 2 To wrdLRow

            'Look for word...
            fndWord = Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(Sht.Cells(wrdLp, "A"), Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "J"))
            
            'If we found the word....then
            If fndWord > 0 Then
                Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "N") = Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "N") & "; " & Sht.Cells(wrdLp, "A")
                fndWord = 0 'Reset Variable for next loop
            End If
            
        Next wrdLp
        
        Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "N") = Mid(Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "N"), 3, Len(Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "N")) - 2)

    Next CommentLp

End Sub```
````

Comment: `Integer`can only work with 32k, change all your `Integer` types for `Long` types and try. Also, you are not getting errors because of the `On Error Resume Next` take it off and you will get a overflow error... Never use the `On Error` unless you know that your code works.

Comment: Thank you is that as simple as replacing the text 'Integer' with 'Long'?

Comment: Yes, and your `On Error Resume Next` should be just above the `fndWord = ...` and just below add a `On Error GoTo 0` so only when no matches are found there won't be errors, but anything else which is wrong will show the error Danny.

Comment: fanatstic! thanking you.